# ios app compile sqlite fts with icu,but it cant get the perfect answer when i input a letter like "z"

Tags: ios, sqlite, icu

In sqlite I:

1. Perform a `create virtual MyTable (tokenize =icu ,id text,subject text,abstract text)`
2. Then successfully `insert info MyTable (id,subject,abstract) values (?,?,?)` 
   so I have the row： 今天天气不错fmowomrogmeog，wfomgomrg，我是谁erz

When I perform `select id from MyTable where MyTable match ‘z*’` it does not return anything，Whenever I search the single letter it returns nothing. However if I search ‘m’ or ‘天气’ or ‘天’，it works.

I know sqlite only support prefix, so I am using ICU. Am I making a mistake?

Note I've looked at the source code on foxmail,it looks to me like I can search ',' 'f' and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Hai Feng Kao's character tokenizer](https://github.com/haifengkao/SqliteSubstringSearch). It can search prefix, postfix and anything in between. It supports Chinese as well. I don't think you can find any other tokenizers which support arbitrarily substring search.

BTW, it is a shameless self-promotion.

If you want to open a database encoded by `character` tokenizer in Objective-C, do the following:

```
#import <FMDB/FMDatabase.h>
#import "character_tokenizer.h"

FMDatabase* database = [[FMDatabase alloc] initWithPath:@"my_database.db"];
if ([database open]) {
    // add FTS support
    const sqlite3_tokenizer_module *ptr;
    get_character_tokenizer_module(&ptr);
    registerTokenizer(database.sqliteHandle, "character", ptr);
}
```

Comment: thanks,i will try it.my app need to support li18n tokenize,it can support?And foxmail can support like 'f' or 'c' in  'abcdef'.

Comment: I don't know what is "li18n", but my tokenizer can support 'f' or 'c' in 'abcdef'. I am pretty sure that ICU tokenizer doesn't support substring search.

Comment: i have been tryed your sqlite,it is great and powerful,i find that it can support i18n.i want to comfirm that your sqlite can use in ios4.3?

Comment: The tokenizer is written in C. It should work on all iOS. However, you have to check if your iOS 4.3's sqlite support FTS3 or not.

Comment: no support，how do i compile sqlite with your tokenizer,I am not familiar with c language

Comment: The tokenizer and sqlite are separated. The demo project illustrates how to register the tokenizer to sqlite. The tokenizer should be compiled with your app. To compile a custom sqlite, check [compiling custom sqlite](http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/06/16/sqlite-full-text-search-for-iphone-ipadyour-own-sqlite-for-iphone-and-ipad/).

Comment: thans ,i can compile sqlite with your tonkenizer in ios4.3,do you tokenizer only support en,zh,jap?what about others?

Comment: I have never tested it on other languages, sorry

Comment: Hai, I'd like to use your tokenizer on my app, but I can't figure out how to use it with FMDB. Would you have an example? Thank you!

Comment: @Winston Here you go!

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try and let you know the results!

Comment: Hai, you saved the day! Your sample code worded like a charm. I thank you very much my friend!

Answer (score 3):

You may also try FMDB's FMSimpleTokenizer. FMSimpleTokenizer uses build-in CFStringTokenizer and according to apple document "CFStringTokenizer allows you to tokenize strings into words, sentences or paragraphs in a language-neutral way. It supports languages such as Japanese and Chinese that do not delimit words by spaces"

If you check FMSimpleTokenizer code, you will find that is done by calling CFStringTokenizerAdvanceToNextToken & CFStringTokenizerGetCurrentTokenRange.

One interesting "fact" is how CFStringTokenizer tokenizes the Chinese words, for example "欢迎使用" will be tokenize into "欢迎" & "使用", which totally makes sense, but if you search "迎", you will be surprised to see no result at all!

In that case you probably need to write a tokenizer like Hai Feng Kao's sqlite tokenizer.

Comment: I've tried to follow you explanation but couldn't come up with a working code. Do you have an example to share? I've tried     CFStringRef SimplifiedChinese_LocaleIdentifier = CFSTR("zh-Hans");
    CFLocaleRef chineseLocale = CFLocaleCreate(NULL, SimplifiedChinese_LocaleIdentifier);
    g_simpleTok = [[FMSimpleTokenizer alloc] initWithLocale:chineseLocale];
    [FMDatabase registerTokenizer:g_simpleTok withKey:@"simple"];

Comment: Please check FMDB sample codes. I made my codes work from them.

Comment: Do you have a link for the sample? Thanks!

Comment: But I really suggest you download the whole FMDB project and check its implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will check!

Comment: Cool, I didn't know FMDB has the tokenizer support.

Comment: CFStringTokenizer is so western. It doesn't make sense to Chinese.