# SQL Server, when to use full text index?

Tags: jquery, sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I am considering using the type-ahead/autocomplete dropdown at http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote on table of AirportNames.

e.g.

```
AirportCode, AirportName
JFK, John F Kennedy Airport
LAX, Los Angeles International Airport
```

In addition to the dropdown showing the JFK Code and AirportName when the text "JF" is typed in, I also want to to display when the user types "nned".

Should I put a full-text index on the AirportName field to make it as fast as possible? Or some sort of full-character index? I'm not sure I've used a full-text index before so was trying to understand it.

TIA
Mark

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224714/what-is-full-text-search-vs-like) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478472/sql-full-text-search-vs-like) might inspire.

Comment: I would roll my own using a dictionary and Levenstein distance.

Comment: In a few words, you may want to use full-text index if you store doument files in your database. No need to use for regular string fields. It may help for large string fields, but in most cases does not worth it.

Comment: I suppose what I really might be aluding to is whether there is such a thing as a full-character index in SQL server. So that searches for partial words are as fast as possible compared with the Like %nnedy% statement which may have to search tables containing say 10,000 records one-by-one.